# How to turn off notifications of docker dashboard?

Tags: docker, docker-desktop, docker-daemon

Well,maybe it seems a ridicilous question but I need some help and think that maybe someone else among approximately 8 billion human on the planet has same issue. Whenever I stop or delete some images or containers on docker dashboard, notification is filling so much space on screen and I cannot click on **'containers'** or **'images'** section again.

I just want to delete/stop containers/images quickly by clicking like "tiki-taka-tiki-taka" but not possible, I need to click **'X'** to close it every single time and this process is so slow.

Usually this kind of products are made for enabling users to make things easier and faster instead of using command prompt but, for docker, using command prompt/terminal is much faster than using dashboard.

Do you know how to disable this notifications?(If it exists)

[image]
or like:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should contact docker's developers for this issue.
For the meantime you could try [Portainer](https://www.portainer.io/pricing-new?hsLang=en) to manage your images, volumes ecc...

Comment: ah ok. so, as far as i understand from your answer is that there is no function to disable that behavior. ok i will contact them and suggest that.

Comment: Yes, it's annoying but this behaviour is baked in the app itself. They should use less invasive badge notifications

Comment: Ok thanks. I have send mail to developers from docker support and contact page. I hope they will deal with it. It is really annoying. And maybe using portainer is logical until they fix it